# How to use IEEE compsoc styled titles in standard IEEE conference latex templates?

Tags: titles, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I am trying to prepare a paper for a conference which provides both Word, PDF and latex templates. However, in the Word/PDF template they used the `compsoc` title style, while the standard IEEE styled title is used in the latex template. What makes me more confused is that the rest of the Word template is in the standard IEEE style instead of `compsoc` style, like this:

[image: Word Template with compsoc-styled title and standard contents]

Is there a way to use `compsoc` style (only for the title) in IEEE conference standard latex template?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) If the conference provides a template, you are usually required to use it as is. Check the conference website for potential special requirements.

Comment: That being said, in what way is the title you show in `compsoc` style? I might be mistaken, but from what I can see with a quick search, `compsoc` papers have the abstract and keywords in single-column format and the remainder of the text in two-columns format, which is not the case here.

Comment: If the confusion comes from the way the authors/affiliations are displayed, which might be different from the LaTeX template, it might just be a discrepancy between the versions of the Word and LaTeX templates posted by the conference organizers on their website.

Comment: @KersouMan Thanks for your comments! I tried to use this `compsoc` template [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-demo-template-for-computer-society-conferences/hzzszpqfkqky), while this template has its own content style (different from standard IEEE style). I will ask the conference organizers to clarify this "mixed" template.  